# Is there a way to split logical conditions on new lines?

Tags: c++, code-formatting, clang-format

for example I want to have my line length at 120 - so generally code is only wrapped after 120 chars. But more often then not we want to have our logcal conditions on new lines:

I have the follow expression:

```cpp
    if ((long_function_name_12345().get_some_status1() != status1) ||
        (long_function_name_12345().get_some_status2() != status2) || 
        force || 
        some_other_logical_bool)
    {
    }
```

When I clang-format it I get:

```cpp
    if ((long_function_name_12345().get_some_status1() != status1) ||
        (long_function_name_12345().get_some_status2() != status2) || force || some_other_logical_bool)
    {
    }
```

Which is not as nice. I want the behaviour to be, once we go over the column limit (120 in this case) then break on any logical block. I have found one way to force it:

```cpp
    if ((long_function_name_12345().get_some_status1() != status1) ||
        (long_function_name_12345().get_some_status2() != status2) || // break
        force || // break
        some_other_logical_bool)
    {
    }
```

It's a bit crap but works but is (IMO) less ugly then wrapping it in `// clang-format off/on` tags...

clang-format version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1~18.04.2

.clang-format contents:

```js
---
Language:        Cpp
# BasedOnStyle:  WebKit
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
AlignConsecutiveMacros: false
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right
AlignOperands:   false
AlignTrailingComments: false
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
# Don't allow function on one line, e.g. 'int f() {return 1;}' - unless its inline
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: InlineOnly
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: MultiLine
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel:  true
  AfterClass:      true
  AfterControlStatement: true
  AfterEnum:       true
  AfterFunction:   true
  AfterNamespace:  true
  AfterObjCDeclaration: true
  AfterStruct:     true
  AfterUnion:      true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  BeforeCatch:     true
  BeforeElse:      true
  IndentBraces:    true
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  SplitEmptyNamespace: true
# have line breaks after operators: 'if (a ||' instead of on the next line ' || b'
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: false
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: false
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
BreakAfterJavaFieldAnnotations: false
BreakStringLiterals: true
# effectively the line length limit before clang-format starts to use multiple lines
ColumnLimit:     120
CommentPragmas:  '^ IWYU pragma:'
CompactNamespaces: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth: 4
ContinuationIndentWidth: 4
# format braces lists (uniform init) like a function param list
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
DeriveLineEnding: true
DerivePointerAlignment: false
DisableFormat:   false
ExperimentalAutoDetectBinPacking: false
FixNamespaceComments: false
ForEachMacros:
  - foreach
  - Q_FOREACH
  - BOOST_FOREACH
IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           '^"(llvm|llvm-c|clang|clang-c)/'
Priority:        2
SortPriority:    0
  - Regex:           '^(<|"(gtest|gmock|isl|json)/)'
Priority:        3
SortPriority:    0
  - Regex:           '.*'
Priority:        1
SortPriority:    0
IncludeIsMainRegex: '(Test)?$'
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ''
IndentCaseLabels: true
IndentGotoLabels: true
IndentPPDirectives: None
IndentWidth:     4
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
JavaScriptQuotes: Leave
JavaScriptWrapImports: true
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: true
MacroBlockBegin: ''
MacroBlockEnd:   ''
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: Inner
ObjCBinPackProtocolList: Auto
ObjCBlockIndentWidth: 4
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList: true
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 2
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 19
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 120
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1000000
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 60
# 'int *p' instead of 'int* p;'
PointerAlignment: Right
ReflowComments:  true
SortIncludes:    true
SortUsingDeclarations: true
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: true
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: true
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: true
SpaceInEmptyBlock: true
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles:  false
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
Standard:        Latest
StatementMacros:
  - Q_UNUSED
  - QT_REQUIRE_VERSION
TabWidth:        8
UseCRLF:         false
UseTab:          Never
...
```

I could not find anything obvious for this - and maybe its a bit too specific.

Comment: Personal opinion, but multiline `if`s are often code smell... If your condition is so huge it doesn't fit in a 120 columns `if`, maybe it's worth moving it in its own function, with a proper name.

Comment: @m88 i think this is an example of a line that does not hit the 120 char limit, but should be wrapped nevertheless

Comment: @m88 4630....number is correct - I want to force even short if lines (exactly like the example) that are not 120 chars long to wrap. If the if statement is over 120 chars (can happen with long variable names with a few namespaces deep).

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could find / come up with (as noted in my updated question):

```cpp
    if ((long_function_name_12345().get_some_status1() != status1) ||
        (long_function_name_12345().get_some_status2() != status2) || // break
        force || // break
        some_other_logical_bool)
    {
    }
```

i.e. by adding some sort of comment it forces clangformat to not merge the lines

Comment: Does an empty comment have the same effect? The word "break" is overloaded with meaning in C and C++, making it a confusing commentary that does not apply. (Disclaimer: I have not used the tool, though it looks nice.)

Comment: yes it does, but I thought people might remove the empty `//` thinking it was left by mistake. Perhaps `// clangfmt` or such would be better :)